# Input Validation for a File

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-core

I am running a security scan on my Application and I keep getting this error message from the scanner. I have tried implementing some options but it keeps bringing this same error up:

```
The ASP.NET application does not use, or incorrectly uses, the model validation framework.
Complex implementation error
```

Is there any other way I can validate the input below especially for `File`?

```csharp
private string _Action { get; set; }

public string Action { get { return _Action; } set { if (value != null) _Action = value; } }

[Required]
[FileExtensions(Extensions = "csv,xlsx")]
public IFormFile File { get; set; }
```

Comment: CSV is text while XLSX is Microsoft Proprietary Binary Fomat for Excel.  There is no way of validating xlsx file except by opening with Excel,

Comment: ohhh okay, please is there any other form of validation I can do? say for instance [max length]? because using the required attribute only also brought up an insufficient input validation error

Comment: what happens if you open manually with Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment`say for instance [max length]?`,I think you can use a custom validation attribute.You can refer to [it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuhzw.gif).

Here is a demo worked to validate the size of a file and the extension of a file:

TestFile.cs:

```
public class TestFile
{
    [MaxFileSize(10000)]
    [AllowedExtensionsAttribute(new string[] { ".txt"})]
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

MaxFileSizeAttribute.cs:

```
public class MaxFileSizeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly int _maxFileSize;
    public MaxFileSizeAttribute(int maxFileSize)
    {
        _maxFileSize = maxFileSize;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(
    object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var file = value as IFormFile;
        if (file != null)
        {
            if (file.Length > _maxFileSize)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public string GetErrorMessage()
    {
        return $"Maximum allowed file size is { _maxFileSize} bytes.";
    }
}
```

AllowedExtensionsAttribute.cs:

```
 public class AllowedExtensionsAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string[] _extensions;
    public AllowedExtensionsAttribute(string[] extensions)
    {
        _extensions = extensions;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(
    object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var file = value as IFormFile;
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        if (file != null)
        {
            if (!_extensions.Contains(extension.ToLower()))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public string GetErrorMessage()
    {
        return $"The file extension is not allowed!";
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult TestFileSize() {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult TestFileSize(TestFile testFile)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
            Console.WriteLine("error");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
@model TestFile
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "TestFileSize";
}

<h1>TestFileSize</h1>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="File" asp-for="File" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Result:
[image]